# Use validity information in angular controller

Tags: angularjs, forms, controller

I have something like

```
<div ng-form ng-repeat="item in aList">
    <input ng-model=item.x someValidatorStuff />
    <input ng-model=item.y someValidatorStuff />
</div>
```

and need to process all valid `item`s. To me it looks like the form has it's model too, namely `item`, but it's just my imagination, no code.

Using

```
<div ng-form="myForm_{{item.name}}" ng-repeat="item in aList">
```

I can access `myForm_name1.$valid` etc. in the controller (though in a child scope). Should I access the child scope somehow (should be easy), or create an own directive, or is there any sane way how to access the validity information in the controller?

Comment: You having _n_ forms on 1 page?

Comment: @dcodesmith Sort of. They're no real forms, just `ng-form`s grouping elements which belong together. Note, that they never get sent anywhere, AFAIK it's just the angular way of defining validity for parts of a page.

Comment: By "doesn't evaluate its argument" you mean that the name of a particular `ng-form` doesn't appear on the scope?

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/yIxajKydN8WqHroHT7UC?p=preview. Don't forget that each ng-repeat has its own scope. So in youre code, the form controller would be added to the ng-repeat scope, not to the controller scope.

Comment: @getOffMyLawn I guess I was confused by what I saw in debugger and forgot about the scoping (as JB Nizet wrote).